# Convert a nullable date to universal time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, utc

When I try to convert a nullable date using `.ToUniversalTime` I receive the error "ToUniversalTime" is not a member of "Date?"

```
Dim tempEndDate As Nullable(Of Date)
tempEndDate = EndDate.ToUniversalTime
```

Does not work.  Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: what *is* EndDate?  try `tempEndDate = tempEndDate.Value.ToUniversalTime` but it wont work when it is null, check HasValue first

Comment: `Public Property EndDate As Date?` --

Comment: @Plutonix -- Even if I try `If EndDate.HasValue Then` I still catch an error on converting EndDate with `EndDate.ToUniversalTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Dim EndDate As DateTime? = DateTime.Now    ' nullable date

Dim tempEndDate As DateTime
If EndDate.HasValue Then        ' check for Nothing
    tempEndDate = EndDate.Value.ToUniversalTime
End If

Console.WriteLine("Before: " & enddate.Value.ToString)
Console.WriteLine(" After: " & tempEndDate.ToString)
```

Output:

> Before: 4/2/2015 10:44:48 AM
>      After: 4/2/2015 3:44:48 PM

`ToUniversalTime` is not a method of `Nullable<T>`, but it is a member of `DateTime` which is exposed as `.Value`.